# Searching for a string in an excel column

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am trying to find a string in an excel spreadsheet but it is only capturing the first row only and neglected to search the rest.

In my code I am using Tkinter to get a user to insert an input and using a `link_url()` to match it with each column cell in excel sheet and if it matches to capture the value of the same row another column.
Here is the same of the excel sheet index:

```
  Name                Link
0  ABC   www.linkname1.com
1  DEF   www.linkname2.com
2  GHI   www.linkname3.com
3  JKL   www.linkname4.com
4  MNO   www.linkname5.com
5  PQR   www.linkname6.com
6  STU   www.linkname7.com
7  VWX   www.linkname8.com
8  YZZ   www.linkname9.com
9  123  www.linkname10.com
```

I create a the following function to search for the input:

```
def link_url():
    df = pd.read_excel('Links.xlsx')
    for i in df.index:
        # print(df['Name'])
        # print(e.get())

        if e.get() in df['Name'][i]:
            print(df['Name'][i])
            link_url = df['Link'][i]
            known.append(e.get())
            return link_url
        else:
            unknown.append(e.get())
            unknown_request = "I will search and return back to you"
            return unknown_request
```

***My Question***

When I search for `ABC` it returns `www.linkname1.com` as requested but when I search for `DEF` it returns `I will search and return back to you` why is that happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: You are looping with a nested if-else. You return in both the if and else. `return` will end the function and exit the loop. In the first iteration if `e.get() in df['Name'][i]` is false you will return that message and not check any further values. (You will never get past the first loop since you return in either case). Your else code should come after the loop body. Since you'll return if you find the value, and if you reach the end of the loop you've not found the value.

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding the question a bit (Henry Ecker is right about the direct issue you are running into), but the solution with Pandas feels a bit weird to me.

I guess I'd personally do something more like this to filter a data frame to a specific row. I generally avoid for looping through data frames as much as I can.

```py
import pandas as pd

my_data = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Name': ['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI'], 
     'Link': ['www.linkname1.com', 'www.linkname2.com', 'www.linkname3.com']}
)

keep = my_data.Name.eq('DEF')
result = my_data[keep]

if len(result) > 0:
    print(result.Link.values)
else:
    print("I will search and return back to you")
```